# Getting a list of livestream moderators in an YouTube channel

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I want to get a list of the moderators in a YouTube channel, with or without authorization. Is there a way to do it with the YouTube api?

Comment: I realize this question has an accepted Answer, but the answer does not address the asked question.  Is there a way in fact, to list all the moderators for a channel?  The LiveChatModertators resource is a point-in-time set of moderators, and suffers the following: Only those who participated in the chat while it was active, are listed; The moderator status of a channel may have changed since the LiveChat took place.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One option is:

- Use [LiveChatModerators](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatModerators) resource for retrieve the lists of moderators for a live chat. The request must be authorized by the owner of the live chat's channel.

See more about how [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatModerators/list).

---

As mentioned on the comments, this is the only documented way I found.

If this way does not meet your needs, submit a ticket on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&;template=874803&pli=1&template=874803).

Comment: I realize this answer was accepted, but it does not address the asked question.  Is there a way in fact, to list all the moderators for a channel?  The LiveChatModertators resource is a point-in-time set of moderators, and suffers the following: Only those who participated in the chat while it was active, are listed; The moderator status of a channel may have changed since the LiveChat took place.

Comment: @Dennis this is the only documented way I found. As alternative, submit a ticket on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&;template=874803&pli=1&template=874803).